# Is there a way to characterize the prime ideals in $\mathbb{R}[x_1,x_2, \dots , x_n]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm studying algebras which can be formed by the quotient of principal ideals in $\mathbb{R}[x_1, \dots , x_n]$, and thus would like to be able to determine which of said principal ideals are maximal, so I can determine which algebras will be integral domains, but I'm not sure of a good way of characterizing the prime ideals in $\mathbb{R}[x_1, \dots , x_n]$, or even just in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Is a good (i.e. better than just checking ideals case by case) characterization of such prime ideals known? Specifically for now I am looking only at principal ideals, but I'd also be interested to know a more general characterization of prime ideals in $\mathbb{R}[x_1, \dots , x_n]$, if possible.

Comment: There is no general characterization of prime ideals in $\mathbb R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, and even for maximal ideals this is a difficult task; see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26497/maximal-ideals-in-the-ring-kx1-xn). But if one restrict ourselves to principal prime ideals, then these are generated by irreducible polynomials.

Comment: @user26857 Are those not the maximal ideals? Or are all principle prime ideals also maximal?

Comment: If we are talking about $\mathbb R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ with $n\ge2$, then no principal prime can be maximal.

Comment: @user26857 Ok, so they just coincide in the case where n=1 I suppose?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: Since $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a PID, we can just focus on the prime/maximal elements. Define

$$A=\{ax+b : a \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}\}$$

$$B=\{ax^2+bx+c : a \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}, b \in \mathbb{R},c\in \mathbb{R} ,b^2-4ac < 0\}$$

Then $A \cup B$ is the set of prime elements of the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

> **Claim 0.** If $a \neq 0$, then $$\mathbb{R}[x]/(ax+b) \cong \mathbb{R}$$
>
> **Claim 1.** If $a \neq 0$, then it seems possible that for $b^2-4ac<0$, we have: $$\mathbb{R}[x]/(ax^2+bx+c) \cong \mathbb{C}$$

I don't know if Claim 1 is actually true.

*Proof of Claim 0.* Write $$\left[x \mapsto \frac{-b}{a}\right] : \mathbb{R}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ for the unique such $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphism that maps $x$ to $\frac{-b}{a}.$ Then the following are equivalent:

- $P \in \mathrm{ker}\left(\left[x \mapsto \frac{-b}{a}\right]\right)$
- $\left[x \mapsto \frac{-b}{a}\right]P = 0$
- $(x-\frac{-b}{a}) \mid P$
- $(x+\frac{b}{a}) \mid P$
- $ax+b \mid P$
- $P \in (ax+b)$

Hence we get an isomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras: $$\mathbb{R}[x]/(ax+b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Claim 1 is fine. For an explicit isomorphism, put $\Delta = b^2 -4 ac < 0$. Since $a X^2 + bX + c = a\left(X + \frac{b}{2a}\right) - \frac{\Delta}{4a^2}$, we have $\mathbb{R}[X]/(aX^2 + bX + c) = \mathbb{R}[X]/\left(X^2 - \frac{\Delta}{4a^2}\right) = \mathbb{R}[X]/\left(X^2 - \Delta\right) = \mathbb{C}$. the last isomorphism being $X \to |\Delta|^{1/2} i$. (Less explicitly, the given quotient is the spliiting field of an irreducible polynomial, and there's only one nontrivial algebraic extension of $\mathbb{R}$.)